# Libgdx and Box2D TiledMap render is not smooth

Tags: libgdx, rendering, box2d, tiled

I'm building simple side scroller game. My player (square) move fast and it interacts with other world objects. Problem is when my player is moving it seems that all world is rendering somehow strange (for example box2d objects are not rendering smooth). When player is not moving everything is ok. Here pic when player is moving[image]

and here when my player stands still
[image]

Here I add my code

```
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;


mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("level1.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, DIV);
    gamecam.position.set((gamePort.getWorldWidth() / 2),    (gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2), 0);


public void update(float dt){
        world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
        if(playerAndGroundTest){
            player.update(dt);
        }

        float x = gamecam.position.x - gamecam.viewportWidth * gamecam.zoom / DIV;
        float y = gamecam.position.y - gamecam.viewportHeight * gamecam.zoom / DIV;

        float width = gamecam.viewportWidth * gamecam.zoom * 2 / DIV;
        float height = gamecam.viewportHeight * gamecam.zoom * 2 / DIV;
        renderer.setView(gamecam.combined, x, y, width, height);

        gamecam.position.set(new Vector2(player.getBody().getPosition().x, (gamePort.getWorldHeight() / 2)), 0);
        gamecam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        update(delta);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        renderer.render();

        b2dr.render(world, gamecam.combined);
    }
```

here's Player update function

```
public void update(float dt){
        body.setLinearVelocity(200 * dt, body.getLinearVelocity().y);
    }
```

Comment: How/where are you rendering the sprite on top of the body? It looks like it's lagging a frame behind the world state. When are you setting the position of the sprite to be the position of the body?

Comment: @bornander I'm using `OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer` as you can see I call its method render after I clean my screen